# Matlab Datetime Plotting

Tags: matlab, datetime, vector

Hey guys I'm doing an assignment and I need to know how to plot a "datetime" vector on the x-axis while plotting a vector of the same length on the y-axis. Time is the datetime vector and it is a 1X7 and v2pt is the other vector which is also a 1X7.. Any ideas on how to go about this?

I also posted a link to my current output and a link to how it should look below!

Thanks in advance!

```
clear
home
close all
%load lab6practice.mat
%load GPS_data1.mat


actual_acceleration =[0,0.012849396249239,-0.224988721385014,-0.084649419341086,0.023981710239712,0.307273995025735]
actual_velocity =[0,0.012849396249239,-0.224988721385014,-0.084649419341086,0.023981710239712,0.307273995025735]
day = [13,13,13,13,13,13,13]
hour = [9,9,9,9,9,9,9]
latitude = [39.132844000000000,39.132662000000000,39.132353000000000,39.132076000000000,39.132001000000000,39.131964000000000]
longitude = [-84.516888000000000,-84.516955000000000,-84.516878000000000,-84.516945000000000,-84.517047000000000,-84.517095000000000]
minute = [14,14,14,15,15,15,16]
month = [2,2,2,2,2,2,2]
second = [0,20,40,0,20,40,0]
time ={'13-Feb-2016 09:14:00','13-Feb-2016 09:14:20','13-Feb-2016 09:14:40','13-Feb-2016 09:15:00','13-Feb-2016 09:15:20','13-Feb-2016 09:15:40','13-Feb-2016 09:16:00'}
year = [2016,2016,2016,2016,2016,2016,2016]

dt = diff(time);
dt = seconds(dt);
dist(1)=0;
tot_dis_trav(1)=0;

for c = 2:length(time)
dist(c)=222240*(asind(sqrt((sind((latitude(c)-latitude(c-1))/2))^2 +cosd(latitude(c-1))*cosd(latitude(c))*(sind((longitude(c)-longitude(c-1))/2))^2))); 
tot_dis_trav(c) = (dist(c) + tot_dis_trav(c-1));
v2pt(c) = ((tot_dis_trav(c))-(tot_dis_trav(c-1)))/(dt(c-1));
end


subplot(2,1,1)
plot(time(1:end),v2pt,'r*')
ylabel('Velocity(m/s)')
xlabel('Time(s)')
title('Estimated and Actual Velocities')
axis([0 10 0 6])
legend('2pt Estimate')
```

Graph I am currently outputting:

[image: Graph I am currently outputting]

How my output should look:

[image: How my output should look]

Comment: Can you replace the first two code blocks with some constant data so we can actually run it?

Comment: just added all of them, hopefully it helps!

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with your code:

1. the assignment to `time` presumably should be `time = datetime({'13-Feb-2016 09:14:00', ...});`
2. in the loop, index exceeds dimension of `latitude` and `longitude`
3. it would be better to pre-allocate `dist`, `tot_dis_trav`, and `v2pt`
4. in `plot`, `time` and `v2pt` don't have the same length.

However, what causes the apparently empty plot is the line `axis([0 10 0 6])`. This sets the `x` axis to days 0–10. Either use `plot(0:6, ...)` to replicate the original plot, or `plot(seconds(time(2:end)-time(1)), ...)` to actually plot seconds.

Comment: Thank you! I was finally able to figure it out.

Comment: If you found this answer helpful, you might consider [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it. This shows to others that the problem is solved. This is of course not obligatory.